# python 3.5 png ellipse shown as rectangle

Tags: python, png, python-imaging-library

In the code below the `png` Ellipse is shown as a rectangle.

Can anybody please let me know the reason and how to fix this?

```
from PIL import Image

ellipse = Image.open("C:\Python\shapes\\ellipse.png")
ellipse.show()
```

Comment: Images are always rectangles.  The only thing that makes a picture an ellipse is the coloring and the transparency.  Try `ellipse.convert('RGBA')` to include the alpha channel.  I'm not positive it'll work, but I'd try it.

Comment: just tried, that does not word

Comment: Could you possibly give links to the desired image and the image currently being gotten?

Comment: I just fixed that by filling the rest of the png file with a color. so the Ellipse is Circumscribed by a colored Rectangle.
Thanks Anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `"C:\Python\shapes\\ellipse.png"` to `"C:\\Python\\shapes\\ellipse.png"` with all double backslashes.

Comment: That doesn't work either,
I just fixed that by filling the rest of the png file with a color.
so the Ellipse is Circumscribed by a colored Rectangle.
Thanks anyway :)